# How to setup different version of a dependency for main and componentTest folder

Tags: java, gradle

How to setup different versions of same dependency for main and componentTest folder.

*For example : *
If I am using xyz dependency then it should be possible that my main folder uses 1.0.1 version of xyz whereas componentTest folder uses 1.0.2 version of xyz

I tried implementing componentTestImplementation but it gave an error saying
Could not find method componentTestImplementation() for arguments[....] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandle ............

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.